# Only change 1 of multiple URL arguments

Tags: python, django

Just some quick code then i'll try and explain what i want to happen.

**urls.py:**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(
                           r'^$',
                           views.NationListView.as_view(),
                           name='index'
                       ),
                       url(
                           r'^(?P<slug>[a-z-]*)/$',
                           views.nation_detail,
                           name='nation'
                       ),
                       url(
                           r'^(?P<slug>[a-z-]*)/(?P<opt_1>[a-z]*)/(?P<opt_2>[a-z]*)/(?P<opt_3>[a-z]*)/$',
                           views.nation_detail__opts,
                           name='nation_opts'
                       ),
)
```

**template.html**

```
{% url 'index' %}
{% url 'nation' nation.slug %}
{% url 'nation' nation.slug nation.opt_1 nation.opt_2 nation.opt_3 %}
```

**url**

```
http://domain.com
http://domain.com/slug
http://domain.com/slug/opt1/opt2/opt3
```

Basically i want to be able to use a template code like:

```
{% url 'nation' opt_2=nation.opt_x %}
```

Where it would prefill the other regex arguments(`slug`,  `opt_1`, `opt_3`) with the existing values and only change the 1 option i've specified instead of having to supply all 4 it is asking for and equate to:

```
http://domain.com/slug/opt1/optx/opt3
```

### **Edit ***

Okay i "think" i've sorted it..

I'll show my amended full code

**urls.py**

```
# Core imports
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

# Local imports
from . import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(
                           r'^$',
                           views.NationListView.as_view(),
                           name='index'
                       ),
                       url(
                           r'^(?P<slug>[a-z-]*)/$',
                           views.nation_detail,
                           name='nation'
                       ),
                       url(
                           r'^(?P<slug>[a-z-]*)/(?P<card_type>[a-z]*)/(?P<role_line>[A-Z]*)/$',
                           views.nation_detail__card_type,
                           name='nation_card_type'
                       ),
                       )
```

**views.py**

```
def nation_detail__card_type(request, slug, card_type, role_line):
    # Pull the nation from the DB based on the slug provided
    nation = get_object_or_404(Nation, slug=slug)

    # Create a dictionary based on all possible 'card_type' values all dictionary values are model functions
    card_type_dict = {
        'all': Nation.players(nation),
        'if': Nation.players_if(nation),
        'gold': Nation.players_gold(nation),
        'silver': Nation.players_silver(nation),
        'bronze': Nation.players_bronze(nation)
    }

    """
    Pull the 'card_type' value from the dictionary also provide a default
    queryset for the page to run on load in the 'else'
    """
    if card_type in card_type_dict:
        card_type_dict = card_type_dict[card_type]

    paginator = Paginator(card_type_dict, 28)
    page = request.GET.get('page')

    try:
        players = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
        players = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
        players = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render_to_response(
        'nations/nation_detail.html',
        {
            'nation': nation,
            'players': players,
            'card_type': card_type,
            'role_line': role_line
        },
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )
```

**nation_detail.py**

```
  <dl class="sub-nav">
    <dt>Card Type:</dt>
    <dd><a href="{% url 'nations:nation_card_type' nation.slug 'gold' role_line %}">Gold</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="{% url 'nations:nation_card_type' nation.slug 'silver' role_line %}">Silver</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="{% url 'nations:nation_card_type' nation.slug 'bronze' role_line %}">Bronze</a></dd>
  </dl>
```

So i set the URL parameter in the urls.py which gets passed to the function in views.py, I know the parameter that gets passed does nothing at the moment just wanted to get the URL changing at the moment, then in the function i just parse the url parameters to a variable in the template then use that variable in the `{% url %}` template tag.

Does this look like it would accomplish what i'm trying to do?

Comment: I don't think it can be possible, but not sure to understand. What values do you want for slug, opt1, opt3? An hardcoded one?

Comment: Well what i'm trying to replicate is http://www.futwiz.com/en/nation/portugal/rating/all/38/0 when you go to 'Card Type' -> 'Gold' `/all/` changes to `/gold/` now if i went to 'Position' -> 'GK `/all/38/` changes to `/all/goalkeepers/38`

Comment: I think what you have to do is creating a new url with `opt2` only, and in the associated view doing a redirection to your wanted URL

Comment: Hey i just added an edit that i think might accomplish what i'm trying to do! Since i'm a total Django noob would you just mind giving it a quick runover to let me know if i'm on the right lines!

Comment: if built-in `url` tag does not fit your need you can write your own tag

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay i "think" i've sorted it..

I'll show my amended full code

**urls.py**

```
# Core imports
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

# Local imports
from . import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
                       url(
                           r'^$',
                           views.NationListView.as_view(),
                           name='index'
                       ),
                       url(
                           r'^(?P<slug>[a-z-]*)/$',
                           views.nation_detail,
                           name='nation'
                       ),
                       url(
                           r'^(?P<slug>[a-z-]*)/(?P<card_type>[a-z]*)/(?P<role_line>[A-Z]*)/$',
                           views.nation_detail__card_type,
                           name='nation_card_type'
                       ),
                       )
```

**views.py**

```
def nation_detail__card_type(request, slug, card_type, role_line):
    # Pull the nation from the DB based on the slug provided
    nation = get_object_or_404(Nation, slug=slug)

    # Create a dictionary based on all possible 'card_type' values all dictionary values are model functions
    card_type_dict = {
        'all': Nation.players(nation),
        'if': Nation.players_if(nation),
        'gold': Nation.players_gold(nation),
        'silver': Nation.players_silver(nation),
        'bronze': Nation.players_bronze(nation)
    }

    """
    Pull the 'card_type' value from the dictionary also provide a default
    queryset for the page to run on load in the 'else'
    """
    if card_type in card_type_dict:
        card_type_dict = card_type_dict[card_type]

    paginator = Paginator(card_type_dict, 28)
    page = request.GET.get('page')

    try:
        players = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
        players = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
        players = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render_to_response(
        'nations/nation_detail.html',
        {
            'nation': nation,
            'players': players,
            'card_type': card_type,
            'role_line': role_line
        },
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )
```

**nation_detail.py**

```
  <dl class="sub-nav">
    <dt>Card Type:</dt>
    <dd><a href="{% url 'nations:nation_card_type' nation.slug 'gold' role_line %}">Gold</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="{% url 'nations:nation_card_type' nation.slug 'silver' role_line %}">Silver</a></dd>
    <dd><a href="{% url 'nations:nation_card_type' nation.slug 'bronze' role_line %}">Bronze</a></dd>
  </dl>
```

So i set the URL parameter in the urls.py which gets passed to the function in views.py, I know the parameter that gets passed does nothing at the moment just wanted to get the URL changing at the moment, then in the function i just parse the url parameters to a variable in the template then use that variable in the `{% url %}` template tag.